# ANT SCRIPT: http url property value is not loaded and giving error java.net.MalformedURLException: For input string: "${amx.admin.port}"

Tags: ant

I am busy with automation of tasks using ant script.
In main properties ( Connection.properties) file I had defined properties values which will be used at runtime in script.

```
admin.url.protocol=${amx.admin.url.protocol}

amx.admin.hostname=shrijeet

amx.admin.port=8120

amx.admin.url=${amx.admin.url.protocol}://${amx.admin.hostname}:${amx.admin.port}
```

Later in script another property file (build.properties) is used at runtime where it uses above values as below.

```
adminURL=http://${amx.admin.hostname}:${amx.admin.port}
```

Now issue is , whenever script is reading value of "adminURL" property it fails with below error

> [AMXAdminTask] 08 Apr 2017 18:15:14  WARN - TIBCO-AMX-CLI-000743: Failed to parse the admin base 
>   url 'http://${amx.admin.hostname}:${amx.admin.port}'. Not a valid url.
>   [AMXAdminTask] java.net.MalformedURLException: For input string: "${amx.admin.port}".

when I hard code value like adminURL=http://shrijeet:8120 , then script works fine. But I need `hostname:port` number to be externalised in main connection.properties.

Please suggect is there is any other way to externalize http url type of properties.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the Ant code that loads the `Connection.properties` and `build.properties` files.

Answer (score 0):

I see i have found solution
where i am creating temporary file ,say build-temp.properties and given tokens in property.
Ex
adminURL=adminuRL_temp

And then i am replacing token with values mentioned in Connection.properies file.

## In build-temp.properties file:

adminURL=adminurl_temp

username=username_temp

password=password_temp

## Target:

```
<target name="setBuildProperty">
<copy file="${ScriptFilesPath}/StandAloneTibcohost/build-temp.properties" tofile="${ScriptFilesPath}/StandAloneTibcohost/build.properties" overwrite="true"/>

<replace file="${ScriptFilesPath}/StandAloneTibcohost/build.properties" propertyFile="${ScriptFilesPath}/Connection.properties">
    <replacefilter token="adminurl_temp" property="adminurl"/>
    <replacefilter token="username_temp" property="username"/>
    <replacefilter token="password_temp" property="password"/>
</replace>

</target>
```

This works perfectly and values are now getting updated.